# Creating new data with OData

Tags: c#, odata, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have an lightswitch project which I export its data via Odata.
In my client application I added service reference (WorkProject).
I created a new data.

```
WorkProject.Employee.CreateEmployee("1","Guy);
```

How can I save the new data via the Odata.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

objApplicationData.SaveChanges(System.Data.Services.Client.SaveChangesOptions.Batch);

See:
A Full CRUD LightSwitch JQuery Mobile Application 
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/126/A-Full-CRUD-LightSwitch-JQuery-Mobile-Application.aspx